# Mapping error in webservice

Tags: apex, webservices, salesforce-id, error

Below is My  webservice it is working for account to opportunity insert, when i inserting a quote  records it showing an error  Insertion is fail error message requried field is missing opportunityId below is my webservice as per my program contact is inserting to particular account,but quotes are not inserting into particulat opportunity.

```
      for(integer k=0;k<opportunity.k++){
         opp = new Opportunity();
         opp.Name = oName;
         opp.CloseDate =system.today();
         opp.StageName =oStage;
          opp.accountId = id;
          oppList.add(opp);

       for(integer l=0;l<l++){
         qu = new Quote();
         qu.Name = req.qName;
       //  opp.CloseDate =system.today();
      //   opp.StageName =req.oStage;

          qList.add(qu);   


      // insert
        insert contactList;
   insert oppList;
   insert qList;
    }
   } 
    }
   }
```

Comment: Can you please fix your code and format it correctly, so that we can help?

Comment: @DancinLlama i updated my code..

Comment: Can you please tell us what you are trying to do exactly?  You're cloning the Opportunity (without specifiying an Id). Same with the Quote.  Also, if you could provide the entire method, that would also help us help you.

Answer (score 3):

Sathya - You should post your webservice method in its entirety so we can see what you are trying to accomplish from end-to-end.

At first blush, you are not INSERTing the Opportunities before you are referencing them in your Quote loop.  That would be why you're getting the "Missing OpportunityId".

Comment: I paste my code can you give me suggestions where i have to modify my code.

Comment: Sathya - again please post your code COMPLETELY from method header through the last curly brace.  If you don't give us the information to help you, we cannot.

Comment: i paste my code from method onwards.

Comment: Excellent!

Ok - so here is the biggest design tenet that you have to keep in mind; you create the references to child objects, you have to insert the parent object fully first.

You need to do a full DML insert on your Opportunity list prior to referencing them in your Quote loop.  That will get you beyond the error.

Comment: May i know where i did mistake..??

Comment: Because you're waiting to insert everything at the same time at the bottom of your class, you don't have the referencial Opportunity Ids when you are creating the Quote objects - hence the error you're seeing.  If you insert the Opportunities PRIOR to creating your quote objects (insert, pull them back in a map so you can key off of them), then create the quote objects you will be good.

Comment: i have to put insert opplist before the quote for loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12168/discussion-between-sathya-and-andy-boettcher)

Comment: Exactly - you have to insert first - then pull the newly created opps into a Map so you can key off of them properly in the Quote loop.